# Save all lines of a terminal buffer into a list after its job finishes

Tags: vimscript, terminal-buffer

I need to save all lines of a terminal buffer into a list after its job finishes asynchronously. I,m opening the terminal buffer like this:

```
  let term_buf_no = term_start(cmd, {'term_name': name, 'term_rows': 10, 'exit_cb': 'ValidateQuickfix'})
```

and the function

```
function ValidateQuickfix(job, exit_status)
  let job = a:job
  let exit_status = a:exit_status
  call s:dbg('job, exit status -> ' . job . ', ' . exit_status)
endfunction
```

just returns

```
DEBUG: job, exit status -> process 6323 dead, 2
```

But how can i get the terminal buffer number inside this callback?

Comment: see `:h job-options`, try to use `out_cb`

Comment: Also `:help job-functions` for manipulating the job object

Comment: Also `:help :make` for running a program synchronously and putting the output in the quickfix list (via `:help errorformat` and others)

Comment: If you’ve ended up with extra accounts we can help you merge them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `job` you get on call-back is a Job object. When used as a string, e.g:

```
echo "Job: " . a:job
```

you get the PID. You can however get a lot of information from the Job spec using various functions, for example `job_info(a:job)`. For example:

```vim
job {
  status             : 'dead'                       # String
  cmd                [                              # List
    0                  : 'ls'                       # String
  ]
  termsig            : ''                           # String
  stoponexit         : 'term'                       # String
  tty_out            : '/dev/pts/31'                # String
  exitval            :  0                           # Number
  exit_cb            : '<SNR>123_ValidateQuickfix'  # String
  tty_in             : '/dev/pts/31'                # String
  channel            {                              # Channel
    status             : 'buffered'                 # String
    id                 :  2                         # Number
    in_io              : 'pipe'                     # String
    err_mode           : 'RAW'                      # String
    in_status          : 'closed'                   # String
    out_io             : 'buffer'                   # String
    err_io             : 'buffer'                   # String
    err_status         : 'closed'                   # String
    out_timeout        :  2000                      # Number
    out_status         : 'buffered'                 # String
    out_mode           : 'RAW'                      # String
    in_mode            : 'RAW'                      # String
    in_timeout         :  2000                      # Number
    err_timeout        :  2000                      # Number
  }
  process            :  15695                       # Number
}
```

---

In your case you can use `ch_getbufnr(a:job, "out")` - this returns the buffer number for the process.

At least on my tests there is a caveat though. If `out_io` is not set to `"buffer"` there is no guarantee the buffer has been written to on call-back. With it set to `"buffer"` the terminal window itself would be empty (as it writes to another buffer).

Testing with `exit_cb` and something like this:

```vim
fun! s:SafeRead(bufnr)
    let txt = getbufline(a:bufnr, 1, '$')
endfun
fun! s:ValidateQuickfix(job, exit_status)
    let bufnr = ch_getbufnr(a:job, "out")
    exe "autocmd SafeState * ++once call s:SafeRead(" . bufnr . ")"
endfun
```

the buffer is empty. Using `close_cb` and the same routine the text is present, but not sure how reliable that is. Without the `autocmd` routine the buffer is always empty on call-back. (You could perhaps do some flush routine).

Best approach would likely be to use some combination of `"out_io": "buffer"`. That would of course render the terminal rather useless at is empty.

You can also use `ch_readraw()` to read the contents from the buffer. `:h channel-more`. This would also render terminal empty.

You could also read specific stream, e.g: `ch_readraw(a:job, {"part":"err"})`

Answer (score 0):

The `term_wait()` function solved it. This functions specifies the number of milliseconds to wait before the terminal buffer is considered synchronized. Default is `10`, after increasing it to `100`, its content is completely read and its last line is really the last one and i can use it in a script further on. Therefore, inside the function defined in `exit_cb` parameter, run the following:

```
...
let term_buf_no = ch_getbufnr(job, 'out')
call term_wait(term_buf_no, 100)
let result = getbufline(term_buf_no, 1, '$')
...
```

Comment: Details on how would be nice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).